# Cpanel Disk Usage

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I was following this tutorial to install demo site replica to my WordPress account.
https://support.learndash.com/articles/installing-the-demo-site-replica/

But, suddenly after replication when I clicked update Premature link everything stopped and now even my wordpress admin not opening.

When I visited CPanel, I saw my disk space ran off:

[image]

But, when I opened file manager to see whats causing problem its showing below statics:
[image]

Now, wp-admin is 933 MB but there is no folder inside it which add ups to 933 MB all of them are in KB.

Comment: CPanel is just showing you directory sizes. Navigate to the wp-admin directory and see what files are in there.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski Navigation.. can you enlighten me on that. Because, picture above shows the content of the directory. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's just showing you the other directories within the directory. It's been a bit since I've used CPanel, Here's a tutorial on using [Cpanel's File Manager](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/file_manager.htm) I googled though. Use that to navigate to wp-admin and then you'll see what files are using all your space.

Answer (score 0):

As per the disk space usages shown ,its showing that you are out of space .

If you have access to WHM , just upgrade the disk space for the website account by editing account option in whm and increase the space first as it requires for storing the temp files.

Answer (score 0):

Upon seeing the i could see that the disk space is almost full.

If you have WHM access you can increase the disk space by `upgrade the current hosting package` or `create a new package for this account.`

For upgrade the hosting package.

1. Login to WHM.
2. Search and click upgrade/downgrade an account.
3. Select the domain and upgrade the package.

For create a new package.

1. Login to WHM
2. Search and open Add package.
3. Create a new Package (increase the package size)
4. Follow the upgrade/downgrade an account and chnage the package vale